# User/database variables in LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

#### Context

I'm trying to create a method to generically solve the "greatest N per group" problem for MySQL using EF Core.

I have a method that takes an `IQueryable<TModel>` and other parameters for pagination and ordering and I'd like fill it with logic to transform an `IQueryable<TModel>` into an `ILookup<TKey, TModel>`.

The best way for MySQL seems to be in the form:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT `x`.`id`, `x`.`group_key`, `x`.`other_field`,
        (@num := if(@group = `group_key`, @num + 1, if(@group := `group_key`, 0, 0))) row_number
    FROM `table` AS `x`
    CROSS JOIN (select @num:=0, @group:=null) c
    ORDER BY `group_key`, `other_field` DESC, `id`
) AS res
WHERE row_number < (@skip + @take) AND row_number >= @skip;
```

Where `@skip` and `@take` are the data about pagination and `group_key` is the key to group the query by.

#### Problem

Given that LINQ and EF Core don't seem to support database variables, the best way that I can see to solve this problem is to:

- order the `IQueryable<TModel>` by the group key and then by the ordering data
- convert the `IQueryable<TModel>` into an SQL string
- put that string inside:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT `x`.`id`, `x`.`group_key`, `x`.`other_field`,
        (@num := if(@group = `group_key`, @num + 1, if(@group := `group_key`, 0, 0))) row_number
    FROM (...) AS `x`
    CROSS JOIN (select @num:=0, @group:=null) c
) AS res
WHERE row_number < (@skip + @take) AND row_number >= @skip;
```

- execute the string and map it back into a `TModel` via [`FromSql`](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#dbset.fromsql).

Of course names like `x` and `row_number` would be replaced by something like `__x` and `__row_number` to avoid conflicts with table names and column names.

#### Question

I can't seem to figure out how to convert an IQueryable into a `SELECT` query. Is there any way to accomplish this? Is there a way to describe MySQL user variables in EF Core?

#### What else have I tried?

I've tried to keep it in the realm of EF Core by calculating for each row the `COUNT(*)` of other rows that are "less than" the given row.
The whole code was a mesh of `Expression`s and works fine.

Unfortunately the resulting query executes in approximately 4.5 seconds (even considering proper indexing). The user variable version above takes 0.03 seconds in comparison (considering ~10000 rows).

---

Currently [I've gotten pretty far](https://pastebin.com/iZL3nbBJ) but I'm unable to figure out how to convert the `keySelector` expression into something I can reference in the `@group := group_key` SQL expression.